# Время RTT для UDP

Tags: linux, udp, синхронизация

Всем привет! Я решил поработать с синхронизацией часов на двух ПК, соединённых напрямую через Ethernet. ПК одинаковы по архитектуре, на обоих стоит Linux Ubuntu.
Мне нужно отправлять UDP пакеты от источника к приемнику и точно знать время односторонней передачи. До имения синхронизации я просто брал и гнал пакет обратно и делил на 2. То есть RTT/2. Но когда я получил синхронизацию и смог измерить односторонние передачи, я заметил, что от источника к приемнику пакет идёт дольше, чем обратно. То есть RTT/2 для этой ситуации не даёт верного ответа (да и вообще даёт ли RTT/2 верный ответ). Почему это может быть, если канал тот же самый, пакет тот же самый?

Для пинга и пакетов ICMP я вижу аналогичную ситуацию, что пакет от источника идёт дольше чем обратный.
Если есть мысли или коды источника и приемника для измерения UDP задержек поделитесь, пожалуйста.
Синхронизацию я делал с помощью PTP и пакета linuxptp.

Comment: Как измеряли RTT?

Comment: @user207200, через clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)  отмечал старт перед sendto() и так же после recvfrom() отмечал конец. RTT брал как разность этих отметок

Comment: Точнее было бы посмотреть в `tcpdump` или `wireshark`. Есть подозрение, что для первой передачи вы еще захватываете запрос-ответ `ARP`.

Comment: Это ведь только для первой передачи, а если я провожу 1000 измерений таких с интервалом в 10 миллисекунд, там тоже заметна разница между отправкой и получением